# Web scraping the titles and descriptions of trending YouTube videos

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, youtube

This scrapes the titles and descriptions of trending YouTube videos and writes them to a CSV file. What improvements can I make?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

source = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

csv_file = open('YouTube Trending Titles on 12-30-18.csv','w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['Title', 'Description'])

for content in soup.find_all('div', class_= "yt-lockup-content"):
    try:
        title = content.h3.a.text
        print(title)

        description = content.find('div', class_="yt-lockup-description yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2").text
        print(description)

    except Exception as e:
        description = None

    print('\n')
    csv_writer.writerow([title, description])

csv_file.close()
```

Answer (score 41):

Why web-scrape, when you can get the data properly through the YouTube Data API, [requesting the `mostpopular` list of videos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list)?  If you make a `GET` request to `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=…&part=snippet&chart=mostpopular`, you will get the same information in a documented JSON format.

Using the [Python client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/youtube/v3), the code looks like:

```
import csv
import googleapiclient.discovery

def most_popular(yt, **kwargs):
    popular = yt.videos().list(chart='mostPopular', part='snippet', **kwargs).execute()
    for video in popular['items']:
        yield video['snippet']

yt = googleapiclient.discovery.build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=…)
with open('YouTube Trending Titles on 12-30-18.csv', 'w') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
    csv_writer.writerow(['Title', 'Description'])
    csv_writer.writerows(
        [snip['title'], snip['description']]
        for snip in most_popular(yt, maxResults=20, regionCode=…)
    )
```

I've also restructured the code so that all of the CSV-writing code appears together, an inside a `with open(…) as f: …` block.

Comment: Great suggestion! I searched but didn't find that API. Are mostpopular and trending synonyms ?

Comment: @Josay When I include the `regionCode` in the API call (`'CA'` for me), then the first 20 results are identical to the list on the "Trending" page, which indicates that they are indeed different names for the same thing.

Comment: Oh, I see; I didn't know the purpose of API, but I will look more into it. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Is the developerkey a thing required to be taken from Google ? If yes, then the scraping doesn't require it and scraping may be better from that point of view. why sign up for something that you don't need to ?

Comment: @WhirlMind Because the HTML structure of the Trending page could change at any time, and is essentially an undocumented API. The YouTube Data API is guaranteed to be stable, and any changes to it will be preceded by a suitable transition period. Obtaining a developer key is a trivial process, if you already have a Google account.

Comment: You web scrape because the google API provides you with a ridiculously small 10k quota units per day.  Some requests may use hundreds or thousands of these units. Almost no requests use only 1 of these units. Thus, using the API gives you severe limitations, so you web scrape to avoid google's nonsense. I mean, is having to design a data-getting system around a quota really the "proper" way to acquire data? To me it seems like unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 15):

**Context manager**

You open a file at the beginning of the program and close it explicitly at the end.

Python provides a nice way to allocate and release resources (such as files) easily: they are called Context managers. They give you the guarantee that the cleanup is performed at the end even in case of exception.

In your case, you could write:

```
with open('YouTube Trending Titles on 12-30-18.csv','w') as file:
    ....
```

**Exception**

All exceptions are caught by `except Exception as e`. It may look like a good idea at first but this can lead to various issues:

- it's hard to know what types of error are actually expected here
- most errors are better not caught (except for special situations). For instance, if you write a typo, you'll end up with an ignored `NameError` or `AttributeError` and debugging will be more painful than it should be.

Also, from the content of the `except` block, it looks like you are only expecting the logic about `description` to fail. If so, it would be clearer to put in the `try (...) except` the smallest amount of code.

For instance:

```
title = content.h3.a.text
try:
    description = content.find('div', class_="yt-lockup-description yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2").text
except Exception as e:
    description = None
print(title)
print(description)
print('\n')
```

**Proper solution**

Google usually offers API to retrieve things such like trending videos. I haven't found it but I'll let you try to find something that works properly. Google is your friend...

Answer (score 10):

I'd definitely look into using an API directly [as @200_success suggested](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/210615/24208) to avoid any web-scraping or HTML parsing, but here are some additional suggestions to improve your current code focused mostly around HTML parsing:

- you could get some speed and memory improvements if you would use a [`SoupStrainer`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document) to allow `BeautifulSoup` parse out only the desired elements from the HTML:

  > The `SoupStrainer` class allows you to choose which parts of an incoming document are parsed.

  ```
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

  trending_containers = SoupStrainer(class_="yt-lockup-content")
  soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml', parse_only=trending_containers)
  ```
- instead of `.find_all()` and `.find()` you could have used more concise [CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors). You would have:

  ```
  soup.select('.yt-lockup-content')
  ```

  instead of:

  ```
  soup.find_all('div', class_= "yt-lockup-content")
  ```

  and:

  ```
  content.select_one('.yt-lockup-description.yt-ui-ellipsis.yt-ui-ellipsis-2')
  ```

  instead of:

  ```
  content.find('div', class_="yt-lockup-description yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2")
  ```
- note how I've omitted `div` tag names above - I think they are irrelevant as the class values actually define the type of an element in this case
- [organize imports as per PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)

Answer (score 5):

I would separate the "input" (finding titles and descriptions) from the output (writing to screen or file). One good way to do that is to use a generator:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

def soup():
    source = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending").text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

def find_videos(soup):
    for content in soup.find_all('div', class_= "yt-lockup-content"):
        try:
            title = content.h3.a.text
            description = content.find('div', class_="yt-lockup-description yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2").text
        except Exception as e:
            description = None
        yield (title, description)

with open('YouTube Trending Titles on 12-30-18.csv', 'w') as csv_file:

    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(['Title', 'Description'])

    for (title, description) in find_videos(soup()):
        csv_writer.writerow([title, description])
```

Disclaimar: I haven't tested this code.