# Scraping Instagram for Hashtag data

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

Over the past few months, I've been actively using python and I have made a few scripts to scrape #hashtag data from Instagram.

It all started with some basic script I had made early 2017 and I have been adding and modifying it ever since. Over the last few months, I made progress in my own skill of Python, successfully adding things like user agent and proxy rotation.

Now that I have a tool that does exactly what I want, I'm looking to:

- Optimize code structure (it's really copying and pasting mostly) and removing 'crappy' code.

Therefore I'm hoping SO can help me analyze my code and suggest optimizations.

My script does the following:

- It analyzes hashtags from the input file (hashtags.txt)
- It then scrapes data from Instagram (like post count, average engagement,...)
- This data is then stored in a .csv. Which is being processed again afterward to remove duplicates.

I also included user agent randomization and proxy rotation.

However, I feel like my code is far from optimal and when I want to add additional things (like catching HTTP errors, retrying on proxy timeouts,...) I'm just adding more levels of indentation so I'm pretty sure there are other options there!

Any help or feedback to optimize my code below is GREATLY appreciated!

```
    # This script is written for personal research and is not endorsed by Instagram.
# Use at your own risk!
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv
import requests
import urllib.request
import json
import re
import random
import time
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from random import randint
from time import sleep

ua = UserAgent(cache=False)
ts = time.gmtime()
timestamp = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H-%M", ts)

def get_csv_header(top_numb):
        fieldnames = ['Hashtag','Active Days Ago','Post Count','AVG. Likes','MAX. Likes','MIN. Likes','AVG. Comments','Hashtag URL','Post Ready Tag']
        return fieldnames

def write_csv_header(filename, headers):
        with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as f_out:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames=headers)
            writer.writeheader()
        return

def read_keywords(t_file):
        with open(t_file) as f:
            keyword_list = f.read().splitlines()
        return keyword_list

def read_proxies(p_file):
        with open(p_file) as f:
            proxy_list = f.read().splitlines()
        return proxy_list

#file 
data_filename = 'Hashtag Scrape ' + timestamp + '.csv'
KEYWORD_FILE = './hashtags.txt'
DATA_FILE = './' + data_filename
PROXY_FILE = './proxies.txt'
keywords = read_keywords(KEYWORD_FILE)
proxies = read_proxies(PROXY_FILE)
csv_headers = get_csv_header(9)
write_csv_header(DATA_FILE, csv_headers)

#Ask for randomisation input fields
low = input("Please enter minimal delay time (in seconds): ")
low_random = int(low)
high = input("Please enter maximal delay time (in seconds): ")
high_random = int(high)

#get the data
for keyword in keywords:
    import urllib, json
    if len(proxies)!=0:
        proxy_ip = random.choice(proxies)
        proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'https':proxy_ip})
        opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support)
        urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
    prepare_url = urllib.request.Request(
        'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/' + urllib.parse.quote_plus(keyword) + '/?__a=1',
        headers={
            'User-Agent': ua.random
        }
    )
    url = urllib.request.urlopen(prepare_url)
    post_info = {}
    response = json.load(url) #response is the JSON dump of the url.

    #defining some script helpers
    x = len(response['graphql']['hashtag']['edge_hashtag_to_top_posts']['edges'])
    i = avg_post_likes = 0
    likes_value = []
    comments_value = []

    #Getting the general tag data
    hashtag_name = response['graphql']['hashtag']['name']
    post_count = response['graphql']['hashtag']['edge_hashtag_to_media']['count']
    hashtag_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/' + keyword
    post_ready_tag = '#' + keyword 
    top_posts = response['graphql']['hashtag']['edge_hashtag_to_top_posts']['edges']
    
    #calculate the active days ago 
    most_recent_post = response['graphql']['hashtag']['edge_hashtag_to_media']['edges'][0]['node']['taken_at_timestamp']
    import datetime
    from dateutil import relativedelta
    post_datetime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(most_recent_post).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    post_cleandate = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(most_recent_post).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    from datetime import datetime, date
    most_recent_clean = datetime.strptime(post_cleandate, '%Y-%m-%d')
    today = datetime.strptime(str(date.today()),'%Y-%m-%d')
    posted_days_ago = relativedelta.relativedelta(today, most_recent_clean).days

    while i <=x-1:
        #Getting data from top posts
        top_post_likes = response['graphql']['hashtag']['edge_hashtag_to_top_posts']['edges'][i]['node']['edge_liked_by']
        post_like = response['graphql']['hashtag']['edge_hashtag_to_top_posts']['edges'][i]['node']['edge_liked_by']['count']
        post_comment = response['graphql']['hashtag']['edge_hashtag_to_top_posts']['edges'][i]['node']['edge_media_to_comment']['count']
        likes_value.append(post_like)
        comments_value.append(post_comment)
        i += 1
    print('Writing ' + keyword + ' to output file')
    with open(data_filename, 'a', newline='',  encoding='utf-8') as data_out:
            post_info["Hashtag"] = hashtag_name
            post_info["Active Days Ago"] = posted_days_ago
            post_info["Post Count"] = post_count
            post_info["AVG. Likes"] = round(sum(likes_value)/len(likes_value),2)
            post_info["MAX. Likes"] = max(likes_value)
            post_info["MIN. Likes"] = min(likes_value)
            post_info["AVG. Comments"] = round(sum(comments_value)/len(comments_value),2)
            post_info["Hashtag URL"] = hashtag_url
            post_info["Post Ready Tag"] = post_ready_tag
            csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(data_out, fieldnames=csv_headers)
            csv_writer.writerow(post_info)
    
    #Randomly pause script based on input values
    sleep(randint(low_random,high_random))
#cleaning up the file: 
destination = data_filename[:-4] + '_unique.csv'
data = open(data_filename, 'r',encoding='utf-8')
target = open(destination, 'w',encoding='utf-8')
# Let the user know you are starting, in case you are de-dupping a huge file 
print("\nRemoving duplicates from %r" % data_filename)

# Initialize variables and counters
unique_lines = set()
source_lines = 0
duplicate_lines = 0

# Loop through data, write uniques to output file, skip duplicates.
for line in data:
    source_lines += 1
    # Strip out the junk for an easy set check, also saves memory
    line_to_check = line.strip('\r\n')    
    if line_to_check in unique_lines: # Skip if line is already in set
        duplicate_lines += 1
        continue 
    else: # Write if new and append stripped line to list of seen lines
        target.write(line)
        unique_lines.add(line_to_check)
# Be nice and close out the files
target.close()
data.close()
import os
os.remove(data_filename)
os.rename(destination, data_filename)
print("SUCCESS: Removed %d duplicate line(s) from file with %d line(s)." % \
 (duplicate_lines, source_lines))
print("Wrote output to %r\n" % data_filename)
print("\n" + 'ALL DONE !!!! ')
```

For those interested, this is how the output file looks:

[image: output file]

Thanks in advance! <3

Comment: Why aren't you using their API? https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Comment: Because I don't need to (yet), and don't really want to either :). I can get this data without using tokens and login credentials. So that's my preferred approach.

Comment: I coded something as similar as yours: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/210613/web-scraping-the-titles-and-descriptions-of-trending-youtube-videos     If you're interested in more web scraping.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This function:

```
def get_csv_header(top_numb):
    fieldnames = ['Hashtag','Active Days Ago','Post Count','AVG. Likes','MAX. Likes','MIN. Likes','AVG. Comments','Hashtag URL','Post Ready Tag']
    return fieldnames
```

has a few issues. `top_numb` is unused, so delete it. You can both construct and return the list in the same statement, but due to its length I suggest that you add some linebreaks in that list. Finally: per [Python 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter), `fieldnames` must be a sequence but needn't be a list - so make this a tuple `()` and not a list `[]` because the data are immutable.

Otherwise:

### Remove redundant `return`s

i.e. the no-op `return` seen in `write_csv_header`.

### Make a `main` function

...for all of your global code, for a couple of reasons - to clean up the global namespace, and to make your code callable as a library for other applications.

### Use f-strings

...for strings like this:

```
data_filename = 'Hashtag Scrape ' + timestamp + '.csv'
```

that can be:

```
data_filename = f'Hashtag Scrape {timestamp}.csv'
```

### Write more subroutines

The bulk of your logic within the main `for keyword in keywords` loop is quite long. Break this up into several subroutines for legibility and maintainability.

### Use `requests`

You're calling into `urllib.request.Request`, but there's usually no good reason to do this. Use `requests` instead, which is better in nearly every way.

### Apply a linter

This will catch non-PEP8 whitespace (or lack thereof) such as that seen in this statement:

```
if len(proxies)!=0:
```

### Imports at the top

In the middle of your source, we see:

```
import datetime
from dateutil import relativedelta
post_datetime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(most_recent_post).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
post_cleandate = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(most_recent_post).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
from datetime import datetime, date
```

It's usually considered better practice to do all of your imports at the top of the source file.

### Don't declare indices that you don't use

This loop:

```
i = avg_post_likes = 0
while i <=x-1:
    # ...
    i += 1
```

should be

```
for _ in range(x):
    # ...
```

You also need a better name for `x`.

### Use `dict.update`

This code:

```
        post_info["Hashtag"] = hashtag_name
        post_info["Active Days Ago"] = posted_days_ago
        post_info["Post Count"] = post_count
        post_info["AVG. Likes"] = round(sum(likes_value)/len(likes_value),2)
        post_info["MAX. Likes"] = max(likes_value)
        post_info["MIN. Likes"] = min(likes_value)
        post_info["AVG. Comments"] = round(sum(comments_value)/len(comments_value),2)
        post_info["Hashtag URL"] = hashtag_url
        post_info["Post Ready Tag"] = post_ready_tag
```

can be greatly simplified by use of `update`:

```
post_info.update({
    'Hashtag': hashtag_name,
    'Active Days Ago': posted_days_ago,
    # ...
```

### Use context management

You were doing so well elsewhere in the file! But then we see this:

```
data = open(data_filename, 'r',encoding='utf-8')
target = open(destination, 'w',encoding='utf-8')
```

Those should also use `with`. You can keep the indentation from getting out-of-control by writing more subroutines.